# Can a download code be used again after a factory reset deletes the game?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I have the Zelda-colored 3DS, which comes with a Link between Worlds download code. And I downloaded it.

Now I will factory-reset the device.

After I do so, will I be able to use the code again to redownload Zelda?

Comment: Probably not. If I recall right, those codes are one time use only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3DS comes setup with an e-shop account from the factory which is tied to the serial#. Even if you factory reset the 3DS, the same e-shop account is still tied to the device. Therefore you will be able to download the game after a factory reset.

Just note that there **is** an option in the e-shop settings that I just noticed which allows you to deactivate the e-shop account itself. Google tells me that this **will** lose all of your purchases if you do this. A standard factory reset is still safe.

This same bit of info is why I was able to get Nintendo to transfer my games to a new 3DS XL via just the serial# from the old 3DS system, though you still have to contact support for them to do that.

Comment: A system transfer does exactly what you want in the last paragraph, no need for contacting Nintendo

Comment: @mathias711 unless you don't have the system for some reason, perhaps.

Comment: Exactly. In my case the 3DS was stolen out of my car, but I kept the serial# down elsewhere. Took Nintendo less than a day and everything was on my new system.